# How to include the SlidingUpPanel from the Umano App which is open on GitHub?

Tags: android, github

I need a Sliding up Panel in my App and found this free source on `GitHub` which is from the Umando App. [GitHub Sliding Up Paned Umano](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

But because I'm new to Android and specially how to work with `GitHub` source, I don't know how to include this library or code in my app.

Has anyone experience with this sliding up panel ? Or can anyone explain me how to include it?

Comment: Now that the library is gradle only, you need to manually make an Eclipse library project for it, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731172/troubles-with-androidslidinguppanel-with-eclipse-error-inflating-class