# Troubles with AndroidSlidingUpPanel with Eclipse - Error Inflating class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, slidingpanelayout

I'm trying to use the [AndroidSlidingUpPanel library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)  (in Eclipse) and I have this error:

```
04-19 20:09:48.413: E/AndroidRuntime(13760): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mendozatourapp/com.mendozatourapp.activitys.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.sothree.slidinguppanel.library.SlidingUpPanelLayout
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DemoActivity" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:paralaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:dragView="@+id/name">  
   </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I downloaded the entire project and imported "main" as library. Then I add this library to my project's java build path. I have the feeling that is a java build path problem. Any idea?

Thank you so much for reading me and take your time to do it.

Comment: You need to make it into a library project for Eclipse.  Did you add a `project.properties` file and an `AndroidManifest.xml` file to the library?

Comment: Yes i did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it working in Eclipse.

The important part is to get your library project created correctly and then link it up to your main project.

For the library project, I created a project.properties file, and also added the jar files for the RecyclerView library, the support v4 library, and nineoldandroids.

I also created a .classpath file in order to make it automatically put the java folder in the build path.

I uploaded the library project that I got working to github: https://github.com/dmnugent80/SlidingUpPanel-for-Eclipse/tree/master

Then, import the library project into your workspace:

[image]

Set it up as a dependency of the main project:

[image]

So, you end up with something like this:

[image]

Then, using this test xml (your xml threw an error about needing a minimum of two children):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/list">

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Main Content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/dragView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/follow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

It works!

[image]

Comment: I quote to you and I am very happy to do it: "It works!". Great job Daniel. Thank you so much.