# Android SDK 24 - The import android.support cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-appcompat

I started to install Eclipse with the current Android sdk, but can't solve this old error ([The import android.support cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299898/the-import-android-support-cannot-be-resolved)), because the old way is not working, cause of the missing "android-support-v4.jar" file. The folder structure has changed in the new android sdk 24, and there is no folder "YOUR_DRIVE\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar".

[image]

Comment: should you not switch to android studio which is the official IDE for Android!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is actually the library project that contains the jar files, they are under the `support` folder that is at the same level as `m2repository`:

[image]

You can use this library project as a dependency for your Eclipse project, or just use the jar directly if that suits your needs.

For more info about setting up a library project as a dependency in Eclipse, see my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36731744/4409409

**Note:**

The m2repository primarily just contains the aar files, which are meant to be used with Android Studio.
You can create library projects from aar files using the method described [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html), but in this case it's not necessary.